# Basification of acid solution. pH calculation. How?

Tags: acid-base

This is my first post.

In order to understand basification I've created a pretty simple example as I currently understand it mainly because.. I really don't understand all of it.

Example:

```
Chemicals = Lye & Vinegar

Reaction  = NaOH + C2H4O2 = H2O + NaC2H3O2

Since the molar ratio of the equation is 1:1...

                Molar Mass          It takes...
Lye     NaOH    39.99710928  = 40   Grams of Lye to NEUTRALIZE,
Acetic  C2H402  60.05196     = 60   Grams of Acetic Acid.
                               *....a Weight Ratio of 2:3
```

**Now to the part I don't understand...**

```
1 liter = 1000 grams
```

At **5%** standard acidity, a **liter of vinegar** has exactly

```
1000 Grams x 0.05 = 50   Grams of acetic acid in it.
```

Thus, **at the above calculated** Weight Ratio of **2:3**...

```
50 Grams of acetic acid x 2/3 = 33.33   Grams of Lye to NEUTRALIZE,
                                50      Grams of Acetic Acid.
                                *....proportional Weight Ratio of 2:3
```

So far...

We have neutralized the 50 grams of acetic acid in the solution to **pH7**.

Question:

What would be the pH of the remainder 950ml of water in the bottle of vinegar? Is it the obvious? pH7?

Is my goal only to neutralize the acetic acid in the solution because the remainder is obviously just water and naturally at a of pH7?

Comment: Your neutralized solution will not have pH 7, because the reaction of sodium hydroxide and acetic acid produces sodium acetate, which is a weak base.

Answer (score 1):

You've made some assumptions that we can deal with, and some that need adjustment.

1) 1 liter of water weighs 1000 grams. Correct. However, 1 liter of 5% acetic acid weighs 1005 grams. No big deal; 1 liter will still contain 50 grams of acetic acid.

2) As the commenter noted, neutralizing the acetic acid gives sodium acetate, a weak base with pH ~9. You can use phenolphthalein as an indicator because it changes color at this pH.

3) The liter of neutralized acid will be homogeneous, so the 50 grams of acid and 33.33 grams of sodium hydroxide will be distributed throughout; any sample of the solution will have the same pH.

(Although it is interesting to do an acid/base titration with phenolphthalein. As you approach the endpoint, a drop of base will splash red, then fade to colorless. The next drop will splash a larger red cloud, then fade; etc. Finally, you might get a huge red cloud and think you are done, but you are just shy of the last bit of neutralization and the solution turns colorless again. The next drop flashes totally red.  The reason I mention this is that you could say that for those few milliseconds when the solution is partially red and partially colorless, the pH is different in different locations, but this is not a steady state, so you mix it till you can get a repeatable measurement.)

4) What you measure when you stick a pH meter into the solution is the concentration of the hydrogen ion (hydronium ion) that results from the water molecules reacting with everything else all over the solution. The acetic acid is a reactant in the original solution that increases the hydrogen ion quantity, but the sodium hydroxide reduces it, so you have made a solution of sodium acetate, pH ~9.

Comment: Just a final thought. If the water I had started with was Deionized water at a starting pH7, would the  solution of sodium acetate then basify to pH7 or pH9 is just what it is?

Comment: Sodium acetate does not give pH = 7 when dissolved in pure water. Sodium hydroxide is a strong base (completely dissociated); water molecules will attach to a sodium ion about as readily as hydroxide ions. Acetic acid is a weak acid; the acetate ion tends to hold onto its proton in acetic acid, and in water, acetate ions (from sodium acetate) will even pick up some protons, so the pH rises to 9.

Answer (score 1):

### Part A

**why the final pH of the solution resulted from the neutralization reaction of a weak acetic acid with a strong sodium hydroxide base in the bottle of vinegar>$7$?**

1. I can infer from the post that you maybe have a misconception about the neutralization reaction and neutrality which hinder the scientific understanding to what happened in the bottle of vinegar when the acetic acid neutralized. You need to differentiate between neutralization and neutrality and enhance your scientific knowledge about the  concepts related to neutralization and neutrality as :

•   Neutralization and neutral $\mathrm{pH}$  are often different things. The neutral $\mathrm{pH}$  is when$\ce{ [H3O +] = [OH-]}$ while the neutralization reaction is when acid and base react to form water and salt, but the salt is not necessarily neutral. The students must success in realizing of the central role of water in neutralization reactions to accept that the neutralization of acid and base is not always given a neutral product.

•   The equivalence point is the point at which the moles of acid are equivalent to the moles of base, according to the equation.

2. When you  have neutralized the$ 50\text{ grams} (50/60 = 0.83\text{mol})$of weak acetic acid by a$ 33.33\text{ grams} (33.33/40 = 0.83 \text{mol})$of strong base sodium hydroxide means that you completely have converted the acid ($\ce{CH3COOH}$) to its corresponding base($\ce{CH3COO-}$), so you will get $0.83\text {moles}$ of sodium acetate ($\ce{CH3COONa}$).
3. The neutralization is fairly straightforward:
   $$\ce{CH3COOH+NaOH⟶CH3COONa+H2O}$$
   Hence, at the equivalent point, the acid in the vinegar bottle has been fully neutralized by the base (no unreacted acid or base present anymore) the bottle will only contain $\ce{H2O}$ and the basic salt ($\ce{ CH3COONa}$). The result, at the equivalence point, will be the same as dissolving($\ce{ CH3COONa}$) in water at the same concentration as you have at the equivalence point.
4. The salt ($\ce{ CH3COONa}$) is  electrically neutral substance formed by cation $\ce{Na+}$ (an acid)and  anion$\ce{ CH3COO−}$ (a base), completely dissociated or ionized in an aqueous solution as :
   $$\ce{CH3COONa   -> Na^+_{(aq)}   + CH3COO^−{(aq)}}$$ 
   a)  Since $\ce{Na+}$  is the conjugate acid of a strong base, it won't be strong enough to react with water; $\ce{Na+}$  actually spectator ion.

b)  Meanwhile, since $\ce{ CH3COO−}$ is the conjugate base of a weak acid, and  therefore strong enough to be able to hydrolyze and accept ions$\ce{ H+}$ from water, so water act as an acid leaving a hydroxide ion $\ce{OH−}$ as :

$$\ce{CH3COO^− +H2O <=>CH3COOH + OH^−}$$
Therefore, at the equivalence point, even though there is no acid or base present,$\ce{ [OH−]>[H3O+]}$, hence the$\mathrm {pH}$ will be >$7$.

### Part B

**Calculating the exact and approximate pH of $\pu{0.83 mol L-1} \ce{CH3COONa}$ in the bottle of vinegar?**

The main reactions which take place are

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\ce{CH3COONa->CH3COO-  +  Na+}&\quad\left (\mbox{Full Dissociation}\right)\\
\ce{CH3COO- + H2O <=> CH3COOH + OH-} &\quad\left(K_\mathrm{{b}\ce{(CH3COO^-)}}=\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{{a}\ce{(CH3COOH)}}}=\frac{10^{-14}}{1.8\times10^{-5}}=5.56 \times10^{-10}\right) \\
\ce{ H2O <=> H+ + OH-} &\quad\left(K_\mathrm{w}= 1\times 10^{-14}\right) \\
\end{array}
$$

The salt  ($\ce{ CH3COONa}$)  is  an ionic salt,and most sodium salts fully dissociate in aqueous solution, and so this "equilibrium" doesn't exist and you can then consider all $\ce{ CH3COONa}$ to be converted to $\ce{CH3COO-}$   ions and $\ce{ Na+}$ ions into the water.
$\ce{ Na+}$  is weak acid it won't undergo hydrolysis.
$\ce{CH3COO-}$   is a relatively strong base it will undergo hydrolysis forming weak acetic acid, which dissociates partially.
The autoionization of water produces very few hydrogen and oxygen ions.so;
The resulting solution in the bottle contains the ions $\ce{  Na+, H3O+, OH−, CH3COO- }$ and undissociated acid  $\ce{CH3COOH}$. In order to specify the concentrations of the five  species present in an aqueous solution of $\ce{ CH3COONa}$ salt, we need five independent equations between them. These are :
1- Equilibria. We have two equilibrium equations:
The hydrolysis of the conjugate base $\ce{CH3COO-}$  :

$$ K_\mathrm{b} =\frac{[\ce{OH-}][\ce{CH3COOH}]}{[\ce{CH3COO-}]}\tag{1}$$

The dissociation equilibrium of water:

$$ K_\mathrm{w} =\ce{[OH-][H+]}\tag{2}$$

2- Mass balance. The mass balance equation that relates the concentrations of the various dissociation products of the substance to its initial concentration, which we designate here as $ [\ce{CH3COONa}]_0$.

For the solution of $\ce{ CH3COONa} $, these equations would be

a- The mass balance equation for the cation  ($\ce{Na+}$), but it is trivial:
$$ \ce{[CH3COONa]_0 =[Na+]} \tag{3}$$
b- The mass balance equation for the anion($\ce{CH3COO-}$)  ; the "total concentration of acetate". This concentration is the sum of all concentrations of species that are related to or derived from acetate. In this solution the relevant species are the acetate ion and acetic acid, so

$$\ce{ [CH3COONa]_0 =[CH3COO-]_T=[CH3COO-] +[CH3COOH]} \tag{4}$$

3-Charge balance. In an ionic solution, the sum of the positive and negative electric charges must be zero; in other words, all solutions are electrically neutral. This is known as the electroneutrality principle.

$$\ce{ [Na+] + [H+] =[CH3COO-] +[OH-]} \tag{5}$$

Substituting $\text{Eq }(3)$ into $\text{Eq }(5)$ yields an equation for$ [\ce{CH3COO−}]$:

$$\ce{ [CH3COO-] =[CH3COONa]_0 + [H+] -[OH-]} \tag{6}$$
Inserting $\text{Eq }(6)$  into $\text{Eq }(5)$ and solving for $ [\ce{CH3COOH}]$,

$$\ce{[CH3COOH]  = [OH-] –[H+]}\tag{7}$$

Substitute these last two equations ($6$ and$7$) into the equilibrium constant $\text{Eq}(1 )$:

$$ K_\mathrm{b} =\frac{[\ce{OH-}]([\ce{OH-}] –[\ce{H+}])} {[\ce{CH3COONa}]_0 – [\ce{OH-}] – [\ce{H+}]} \tag{8}$$

substitute these two expressions (${[\ce{OH-}]=\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{[\ce{H+}]}}$ ) and ($K_\mathrm{b} =\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a}}$) into the $\text{Eq}(8 )$:

$$K_\mathrm{a}=\frac{\mathrm{[H^+]}{([\ce{CH3COONa}]_0 + \mathrm{[H^+]} - K_\mathrm{w}/\mathrm{[H^+])} }}{( K_\mathrm{w}/\mathrm{[H^+]} - \mathrm{[H^+])}} \tag{9}$$
which is cubic equation in $\ce[{H^+}]$  that is solved to get exact value of $\ce[{H^+}]$
; it becomes as

$$\
 [\ce{H+}]^3 
+( K_\mathrm{a}+[\ce{CH3COONa}]_0) [\ce{H+}]^2 
  -K_\mathrm{w}[\ce{H+}] -    K_\mathrm{w} K_\mathrm{a}
  \tag{10}
$$
**"This is exact. Now to the approximations."**

The $\text{Eq}( 9)$  can be simplified If we assume that $\ce{[OH−] >> [H+]}$ in basic solution, then $\text{Eq} (9)$ can be simplified to

$$K_\mathrm{a}=\frac{\mathrm[{H^+}]([\ce{CH3COONa}]_0  - K_\mathrm{w}/\mathrm{[H^+])} }{ K_\mathrm{w}/\mathrm{[H^+]} } \tag{11}$$
which is quadratic equation in$\ce[{H^+}]$  that is solved to get approximate value of $\ce[{H^+}]$ :
; it becomes as

$$\ce[{CH3COONa}]_0 [\ce{H+}]^2 
    -K_\mathrm{w}[\ce{H+}] -    K_\mathrm{w} K_\mathrm{a}
  \tag{12}=0
$$
The $\text{Eq} (11)$  can be simplified further  If we assume that $\ce{[OH−] << [CH3COONa]_0}$ , then $\text{Eq} (11 )$ can be reduced to
$$K_\mathrm{a}\approx\frac{\mathrm[{H^+}] [\ce{CH3COONa}]_0    }{ K_\mathrm{w}/\mathrm{[H^+]} } \tag{13}$$

Or
$$[\ce{H+}]\approx\sqrt{\frac{K_\mathrm{a}K_\mathrm{w}}{[\ce{CH3COONa}]_0}}\tag{14}$$

**- Comparing of the $ [\ce{H+}]$ values resulted from solution the three derived equations when**: $$[\ce{CH3COONa}]_0=\frac{50\text{grams}}{(60\text{grams\mol)}\times{1\text{Liter}}}=\frac{33.33\text{grams}}{(40\text{grams\mol)}\times{1\text{Liter}}}={\color{red}{0.83325}\mathrm{M}}$$
and 
$K_\mathrm{a}={\color{green}{{1.8\times10^{-5}}}}$

1- The completely exact answer solution using cubic equation ($10$)by[wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X%5E3%2B(1.8*10%5E-5%2B0.83325)*X%5E2+-1*10%5E-14*X-1.8*10%5E-5*1*10%5E-14%3D0)

$[\ce{H+}] =4.6478\times{10^{-10}}\text{M}$ , $\mathrm{pH}=9.3327526$

2- The approximate answer solution using quadratic equation ($12$)[wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=9492504056afc5ada7c27e54c54e4bec)

$[\ce{H+}] =4.64782\times{10^{-10}}\text{M}$ , $\mathrm{pH}=9.3327507$

3- The further approximate answer solution using the reduced equation ($14$) $[\ce{H+}] =4.657\times{10^{-10}}\text{M}$,$\mathrm{pH}=9.3318$